# How to count character occurrences using SIMD

Tags: c, simd, avx, avx2

I am given a array of lowercase characters (up to 1.5Gb) and a character c. And I want to find how many occurrences are of the character c using AVX instructions.

```
    unsigned long long char_count_AVX2(char * vector, int size, char c){
    unsigned long long sum =0;
    int i, j;
    const int con=3;
    __m256i ans[con];
    for(i=0; i<con; i++)
        ans[i]=_mm256_setzero_si256();

    __m256i Zer=_mm256_setzero_si256();
    __m256i C=_mm256_set1_epi8(c);
    __m256i Assos=_mm256_set1_epi8(0x01);
    __m256i FF=_mm256_set1_epi8(0xFF);
    __m256i shield=_mm256_set1_epi8(0xFF);
    __m256i temp;
    int couter=0;
    for(i=0; i<size; i+=32){
        couter++;
        shield=_mm256_xor_si256(_mm256_cmpeq_epi8(ans[0], Zer), FF);
        temp=_mm256_cmpeq_epi8(C, *((__m256i*)(vector+i)));
        temp=_mm256_xor_si256(temp, FF);
        temp=_mm256_add_epi8(temp, Assos);
        ans[0]=_mm256_add_epi8(temp, ans[0]);
        for(j=1; j<con; j++){
            temp=_mm256_cmpeq_epi8(ans[j-1], Zer);
            shield=_mm256_and_si256(shield, temp);
            temp=_mm256_xor_si256(shield, FF);
            temp=_mm256_add_epi8(temp, Assos);
            ans[j]=_mm256_add_epi8(temp, ans[j]);
        }
    }
    for(j=con-1; j>=0; j--){
        sum<<=8;
        unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char*)&(ans[j]);
        for(i=0; i<32; i++){
            sum+=*(ptr+i);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: What is your character format? ASCII or some kind of Unicode?

Comment: The format is ASCII

Comment: AVX1 or AVX2? What have you tried? Hint: Check `_mm256_cmpeq_epi8` and `_mm256_sub_epi8` for the most inner loop. After 255 iterations you need to start combining two bytes into one `uint16`, and so on

Comment: AVX2, well until now I have an array of 4 __m256i variables and I am pushing the overflow from index 0 until 3.

Comment: Can you show some code of what you did? For adding 8bit integers to larger integers, what this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541127/

Comment: `_mm256_cmpeq_epi8` will get you a `-1` in each byte. If you subtract that from a counter (using `_mm256_sub_epi8`) you can directly count up to 255 or 128, i.e., your most inner loop should just contain these two intrinsics.

Comment: @Adamos2468: I added efficient horizontal-sum code to chtz's answer, using `vpsadbw` against zero for byte to qword.  And efficient shuffles for 256-bit down to 64-bit like [Fastest way to do horizontal float vector sum on x86](//stackoverflow.com/q/6996764).

Comment: One core can't usually saturate DRAM bandwidth, so for *large* inputs it might be worth using multiple threads (especially if you already have a worker thread started and can just send it a function pointer and args).  You tagged this [tag:parallel-processing], are you asking for OpenMP or something as well?

Answer (score 4):

I'm intentionally leaving out some parts, which you need to figure out yourself (e.g. handling lengths that aren't a multiple of `4*255*32` bytes), but your most inner loop should look something like the one starting with `for(int i...)`:

**`_mm256_cmpeq_epi8` will get you a -1 in each byte, which you can use as an integer**. If you subtract that from a counter (using `_mm256_sub_epi8`) you can directly count up to 255 or 128.  The inner loop contains just these two intrinsics.  You have to stop and

```
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdint.h>

static inline
__m256i hsum_epu8_epu64(__m256i v) {
    return _mm256_sad_epu8(v, _mm256_setzero_si256());  // SAD against zero is a handy trick
}

static inline
uint64_t hsum_epu64_scalar(__m256i v) {
    __m128i lo = _mm256_castsi256_si128(v);
    __m128i hi = _mm256_extracti128_si256(v, 1);
    __m128i sum2x64 = _mm_add_epi64(lo, hi);   // narrow to 128

    hi = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(sum2x64, sum2x64);
    __m128i sum = _mm_add_epi64(hi, sum2x64);  // narrow to 64
    return _mm_cvtsi128_si64(sum);
}


unsigned long long char_count_AVX2(char const* vector, size_t size, char c)
{
    __m256i C=_mm256_set1_epi8(c);

    // todo: count elements and increment `vector` until it is aligned to 256bits (=32 bytes)
    __m256i const * simd_vector = (__m256i const *) vector;
     // *simd_vector is an alignment-required load, unlike _mm256_loadu_si256()

    __m256i sum64 = _mm256_setzero_si256();
    size_t unrolled_size_limit = size - 4*255*32 + 1;
    for(size_t k=0; k<unrolled_size_limit ; k+=4*255*32) // outer loop: TODO
    {
        __m256i counter[4]; // multiple counter registers to hide latencies
        for(int j=0; j<4; j++)
            counter[j]=_mm256_setzero_si256();
        // inner loop: make sure that you don't go beyond the data you can read
        for(int i=0; i<255; ++i)
        {   // or limit this inner loop to ~22 to avoid branch mispredicts
            for(int j=0; j<4; ++j)
            {
                counter[j]=_mm256_sub_epi8(counter[j],           // count -= 0 or -1
                                           _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(*simd_vector, C));
                ++simd_vector;
            }
        }

        // only need one outer accumulator: OoO exec hides the latency of adding into it
        sum64 = _mm256_add_epi64(sum64, hsum_epu8_epu64(counter[0]));
        sum64 = _mm256_add_epi64(sum64, hsum_epu8_epu64(counter[1]));
        sum64 = _mm256_add_epi64(sum64, hsum_epu8_epu64(counter[2]));
        sum64 = _mm256_add_epi64(sum64, hsum_epu8_epu64(counter[3]));
    }

    uint64_t sum = hsum_epu64_scalar(sum64);

    // TODO add up remaining bytes with sum.
    // Including a rolled-up vector loop before going scalar
    //  because we're potentially a *long* way from the end

    // Maybe put some logic into the main loop to shorten the 255 inner iterations
    // if we're close to the end.  A little bit of scalar work there shouldn't hurt every 255 iters.

    return sum;
}
```

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/do5e3- (clang is slightly better than gcc at unrolling the most inner loop: gcc includes some useless `vmovdqa` instructions that will bottleneck the front-end if the data is hot in L1d cache, preventing us from running close to 2x 32-byte loads per clock)

Comment: The widening to epu64 can and should be done with `_mm256_sad_epu8(counter, _mm256_setzero_si256())`, then `_mm256_add_epi64` into one vector which you hsum at the very end.

Comment: I added code that does that hsum, and an outer loop size limit.  Note that clang uses indexed addressing modes, so it's no closer than gcc to running at 2 loads per clock on Haswell/Skylake. :(  They'll unlaminate from `vpcmpeqb` into separate uops in the issue stage.  Writing it with the loop bounds as pointer-comparison might be a better bet, and get clang to just do pure pointer increments instead of silly indexing.  e.g. `const char *endp = min(buf + size, buf + 4*255*32)` or something.

Comment: Thanks @PeterCordes for improving this! I guess for gcc it would be better to manually unroll the inner loop (i.e., create 4 variables instead of an array). Nice trick with `vpsadbw`.

Comment: Yeah, that might help GCC avoid the stupid `vmovdqa` instructions.  Worth trying if you're curious.  Or file a missed-optimization bug; it's already optimized away any store/reload of the array of 4 vectors, and this is clearly something that it *should* be able to optimize.  Anyway, gcc's `-funroll-loops` is only enabled manually or as part of `-fprofile-use`; for large codebases unrolling every loop hurts more than it helps, but profile-use will identify the hot loops and unroll them.  I'd assume unrolling would let it avoid extra movdqa as well.

Comment: The `vpsadbw` trick is relatively well known for hsumming 8-bit data, and worth using even for signed by XORing to range-shift and then subtracting the `16 or 32 * 128` bias at the end.  I think Agner Fog's optimization guide mentions it, or at least his VectorClass library uses it.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't insist on using only SIMD instructions, you can make use
of the [VPMOVMSKB](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmovmskb) instruction in combination with the [POPCNT](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/popcnt) instruction. The former combines the highest bits of each byte into a 32-bit integer mask and the latter counts the `1` bits in this integer (=the count of char matches).

```
int couter=0;
for(i=0; i<size; i+=32) {
  ...
  couter += 
    _mm_popcnt_u32( 
      (unsigned int)_mm256_movemask_epi8( 
        _mm256_cmpeq_epi8( C, *((__m256i*)(vector+i) ))
      ) 
    );
  ...
}
```

I haven't tested this solution, but you should get the gist.

Comment: I had the same idea in OP's other, now-deleted question. GMTA.

Comment: Doing `_mm256_movemask_epi8` and `_mm_popcnt_u32` in the inner loop is far less efficient than `_mm256_sub_epi8`

Comment: I guess so. But it is an alternative that is worth mentioning for its simplicity.

Comment: Possibly useful as part of a cleanup loop, or **for an unaligned start/end where you shift out some of the bits before you popcnt, using a shift count calculated from the overlap**.  Otherwise the more reasonable "simple" version is putting the `psadbw` epu8->epu64 hsum inside the inner loop and using `_mm256_add_epi64`.  That's only 1 extra instruction per vector vs. the efficient way, vs. 2 (`vpcmpeqb` + `vpmovmskb` + `popcnt` + `add` vs. `vpcmpeqb` (+`vpsadbw`) + `vpsubb` / `q`).

Answer (score 3):

Probably the fastest: [memcount_avx2](https://gist.github.com/powturbo/2b06a84b6008dfffef11e53edba297d3) and [memcount_sse2](https://gist.github.com/powturbo/456edcae788a61ebe2fc)

```
size_t memcount_avx2(const void *s, int c, size_t n) 
{    
  __m256i cv = _mm256_set1_epi8(c), 
          zv = _mm256_setzero_si256(), 
         sum = zv, acr0,acr1,acr2,acr3;
  const char *p,*pe;    

  for(p = s; p != (char *)s+(n- (n % (252*32)));) 
  { 
    for(acr0 = acr1 = acr2 = acr3 = zv, pe = p+252*32; p != pe; p += 128) 
    {
      acr0 = _mm256_sub_epi8(acr0, _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(cv, _mm256_lddqu_si256((const __m256i *)p))); 
      acr1 = _mm256_sub_epi8(acr1, _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(cv, _mm256_lddqu_si256((const __m256i *)(p+32)))); 
      acr2 = _mm256_sub_epi8(acr2, _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(cv, _mm256_lddqu_si256((const __m256i *)(p+64)))); 
      acr3 = _mm256_sub_epi8(acr3, _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(cv, _mm256_lddqu_si256((const __m256i *)(p+96)))); 
      __builtin_prefetch(p+1024);
    }
    sum = _mm256_add_epi64(sum, _mm256_sad_epu8(acr0, zv));
    sum = _mm256_add_epi64(sum, _mm256_sad_epu8(acr1, zv));
    sum = _mm256_add_epi64(sum, _mm256_sad_epu8(acr2, zv));
    sum = _mm256_add_epi64(sum, _mm256_sad_epu8(acr3, zv));
  } 

  for(acr0 = zv; p+32 < (char *)s + n; p += 32)  
    acr0 = _mm256_sub_epi8(acr0, _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(cv, _mm256_lddqu_si256((const __m256i *)p))); 
  sum = _mm256_add_epi64(sum, _mm256_sad_epu8(acr0, zv));

  size_t count = _mm256_extract_epi64(sum, 0) 
               + _mm256_extract_epi64(sum, 1) 
               + _mm256_extract_epi64(sum, 2) 
               + _mm256_extract_epi64(sum, 3);  

  while(p != (char *)s + n) 
      count += *p++ == c;
  return count;
}
```

Benchmark skylake i7-6700 - 3.4GHz - gcc 8.3:

memcount_avx2 : 28 GB/s
memcount_sse: 23 GB/s
char_count_AVX2 : 23 GB/s (from [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54543009/6264478))

Comment: You can use `_mm256_sub_epi8` to accumulate the cmpeq results instead of wasting instructions in the outer loop.  Also, this code is too compact for its own good and not indented properly.  (Maybe a tab vs. space problem in the SO markdown?)  It took me a while to find where you were zeroing `acr0..3` between inner-loop iterations; would make more sense to declare them *inside* the outer loop.  I don't think there are any compilers that support AVX2 but not C99.  I'd also do the end-pointer calculations on separate source lines.

Comment: I don't see what you mean, by wasting instructions

Comment: If you use `acr0 = _mm256_sub_epi8(acr0, cmp(...))` then the outer loop can just use `acr0` instead of `_mm256_sub_epi8(zv, acr0)`.  Use `x -= -1` instead of `x += -1` inside the inner loop.  That `sub` is a wasted instruction in your version.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I've made the changes and a new benchmark