# x86 intrinsics - efficient way to pad out 8 * 32-bit masks to 8 * 64-bit masks?

Tags: c++, x86, intrinsics, avx2

I am trying to increment a set of 8 x 64 bit uints depending on the result of a compare of 8 x 32-bit float comparisons.

I am storing the mask result of the comparison in a __m256 register and have the values to be increment stored in a __m256i[2]

Is there an efficient way of padding out the 256-bit mask to 512-bit? I am using:

```cpp
    const __m256 paddedMask[2] = {
        _mm256_set_ps(mask.m256_f32[0], mask.m256_f32[0], mask.m256_f32[1], mask.m256_f32[1],
            mask.m256_f32[2], mask.m256_f32[2], mask.m256_f32[3], mask.m256_f32[3]),
        _mm256_set_ps(mask.m256_f32[4], mask.m256_f32[4], mask.m256_f32[5], mask.m256_f32[5],
            mask.m256_f32[6], mask.m256_f32[6], mask.m256_f32[7], mask.m256_f32[7])
    };
```

Complete compilable example can be found here: https://godbolt.org/z/3Y3PTnoj8

Answer (score 2):

You could use sign-extension (`vpmovsxdq`).

```
extern __m256 cmp_ps;
extern __m256i values_lo;
extern __m256i values_hi;

// cast from float to integer
__m256i cmp_32 = _mm256_castps_si256(cmp_ps);

// extact each 128-bit half
__m128i lo_cmp_32 = _mm256_castsi256_si128(cmp_epi32); 
__m128i hi_cmp_32 = _mm256_extracti128_si256(cmp_epi32, 1);

// sign extend i32x4 to i64x4
__m256i lo_cmp_64 = _mm256_cvtepi32_epi64(lo_cmp_32);
__m256i hi_cmp_64 = _mm256_cvtepi32_epi64(hi_cmp_32);

// compare mask is either -1 or 0
// subtracting -1 is the same as adding 1
values_lo = _mm256_sub_epi64(values_lo, lo_cmp_64);
values_hi = _mm256_sub_epi64(values_hi, hi_cmp_64);
```

If you want to increment by other than 1 then just
use a `_mm256_and_si256` then add, not a blend.

However, moving values from the low 128-bits to the high 128-bits is fairly expensive. You should consider re-ordering the accumulators so only unpack instructions (`vpunpckhdq/vpunpckldq`) are needed.

Edit:
Alternatively, using `_mm256_permutevar8x32_epi32` for the hi 128-bits is cheaper than an extract and broadcast (sign extend).

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Great idea using the subtract with the mask. That does save doing an add/blend. I have seen some posts about some permutevar instructions but was unsure if they were the correct thing to do.  I'll do some investigation into that :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing this in a loop with the same vector of counters for all FP compares, you can just **use 32-bit counts** (`_mm256_sub_epi32(counts32, _mm256_castps_epi32(compare))`) **for up to 2^32-1 iterations of an inner loop before needing to widen and add to the 64-bit counts**.  (With zero-extension which is easier than sign-extension for the high half.)

The same idea of using an inner loop to defer widening is shown in full-code answers to [How to count character occurrences using SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541129/how-to-count-character-occurrences-using-simd) (where the inner loop can only run at most 255 times, and there's a special trick to horizontal-sum 8-bit to 64-bit, unlike in this case.)

You might unroll with two accumulator vectors, since some CPUs can sustain two FP compares and two `vpsubd` integer accumulates per clock, so you'd avoid a latency bottleneck.  (Alder Lake can do 3 loads per clock, enough to feed more than 1 FP compare per clock even if both operands come from memory.  https://uops.info/.)  Or not, if you expect your data to usually not be hot in L1d cache so L2 or worse bandwidth will be a bottleneck, especially if you need two loads per FP compare.  Or if you're comparing the results of a more expensive computation.

Amortizing the cost of widening makes it basically irrelevant except for overall code-size, except for very small arrays where it still has to happen once for only a couple vectors of FP compares.  So we should aim for small uop-cache footprint and/or needing vector constants.

---

If you ultimately want to sum down to a single scalar, position doesn't matter so we can add odd/even pairs like `_mm256_and_si256(v, _mm256_set1_epi64(0x00000000FFFFFFFF))` and `_mm256_srli_epi64(v, 32)`, or do the low halves with with shift left then right by 32 to zero-extend into the containing 64-bit element.  Probably a better way to avoid loading a vector constant is `_mm256_unpacklo_epi32` and `_mm256_unpackhi_epi32(v, _mm256_setzero_si256())` (these operate in-lane, the same shuffle within each 128-bit lane).

Or if you limit the inner loop to 2^31-1 or 2^30 iterations so adding pairs still won't overflow 32 bits, you can extract the high half, `_mm_add_epi32`, and `_mm256_cvtepu32_epi64` to zero-extend.  Then add to a 64-bit accumulator with `_mm256_add_epi64`.  This saves instructions and is still totally negligible cost since it runs so infrequently.

If position within the vector does matter, then similar to what @aqrit shows but with zero-extension instead of sign-extension: extract the high half and use `vpmovzxdq` twice (`_mm256_cvtepu32_epi64`), or use `vpermd` + `vpsrlq` (shift by 32) on the high half.

---

If you aren't keeping the same vector(s) of 64-bit counters across multiple vectors of FP compares, then yeah you probably need to widen each mask vector separately.

If you're using a strategy where zero-extending is cheaper than sign-extending, you might start with `_mm256_abs_epi32` (`vpabsd`) to turn `-1` (all-ones) into `+1`.  But if you're extracting the high half to set up for 2x `vpmovsxdq` then just use `vpsubq` to accumulate.

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea of the two accumulators so I will try and roll that out negating the need to convert between 32-bit and 64-bit :-)