# Using `static` on a AVX2 counter function increases performance ~10x in MT environment without any change in Compiler optimizations

Tags: c++, multithreading, optimization, avx2

The function takes about 20-35ms when ran with `static inline` on GCC or Clang with at least O1 (on O0 its the same 400-600ms like without the static keyword), when static is removed the function takes +400ms to execute on an array with 1bil bytes/chars, when single threaded the function's time doesn't change whether its used with static or without. On MSVC it will always take 400 or more ms even with O2i and avx2 arch.

If I just replace the AVX2 code with a simple call to std::count(begin, end, target) it will run just as fast as the AVX2 no matter if static is specified or not (even on MSVC this time)

Code:

```cpp
static inline uint64_t opt_count(const char* begin, const char* end, const char target) noexcept {

    const __m256i avx2_Target = _mm256_set1_epi8(target);
    uint64_t result = 0;

    static __m256i cnk1, cnk2;
    static __m256i cmp1, cmp2;
    static uint32_t msk1, msk2;
    uint64_t cst;

    for (; begin < end; begin += 64) {
        cnk1 = _mm256_load_si256((const __m256i*)(begin));
        cnk2 = _mm256_load_si256((const __m256i*)(begin+32));

        cmp1 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(cnk1, avx2_Target);
        cmp2 = _mm256_cmpeq_epi8(cnk2, avx2_Target);

        msk1 = _mm256_movemask_epi8(cmp1);
        msk2 = _mm256_movemask_epi8(cmp2);
        // Casting and shifting is faster than 2 popcnt calls
        cst = static_cast<uint64_t>(msk2) << 32;
        result += _mm_popcnt_u64(msk1 | cst);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Caller:

```cpp
uint64_t opt_count_parallel(const char* begin, const char* end, const char target) noexcept {
    const size_t num_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()*2;
    const size_t total_length = end - begin;
    if (total_length < num_threads * 2) {
        return opt_count(begin, end, target);
    }

    const size_t chunk_size = (total_length + num_threads - 1) / num_threads;

    std::vector<std::future<uint64_t>> futures;
    futures.reserve(num_threads);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        const char* chunk_begin = begin + (i * chunk_size);
        const char* chunk_end = std::min(end, chunk_begin + chunk_size);

        futures.emplace_back(std::async(std::launch::async, opt_count, chunk_begin, chunk_end, target));
    }

    uint64_t total_count = 0;
    for (auto& future : futures) {
        total_count += future.get();
    }

    return total_count;
}
```

In a different file I allocate a buffer with new, align it ,memset '/n'  and every other char set to 'x' and time each iteration of the `opt_count_parallel` call and print its output.

I have tried using thread and future and both have more or less the same result.

Here is the godbolt diff view: https://godbolt.org/z/9P87bndsb
, I don't see much difference in the assembly but I'm not knowledgeable enough to understand the small differences

I've also tried assigning avx2_Target outside the opt_count, in opt_count_parallel which made no difference

I looked at GCC's fopt-info and the output was same on both occasions, I've also tried force inlining and noalign but again no noticeable difference

I've also tried debugging/profiling but its a bit of an annoyance since it's speedup is lost on -O0 and profiling just shows that everything takes uniformly longer to execute

Comment: I forgot to specify my compiler options:

g++ -march=native -Ofast -funroll-loops -fno-exceptions -std=c++23 ...

Comment: BTW this is not the problem you're talking about, but I strongly recommend removing `static` from your local variables. They're causing unnecessary stores of the associated values to memory, otherwise they'll just be in registers.

Comment: Okay @harold, I'll do that. Lemme know if any other info is needed

Comment: What CPU?  Small code-gen differences like code alignment can matter especially on Skylake-family ([How can I mitigate the impact of the Intel jcc erratum on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61256646)).  Usually less on other CPUs.

Comment: Intel i9-13900H, on linux I've tried with all CPU mitigations off kernel wise with no drastic change  @PeterCordes

Comment: The JCC erratum is a correctness problem (not "just" security) fixed in microcode by disabling the uop cache for 32-byte chunks that include a JCC.  But not on your CPU, it's not Skylake-family.  It's Raptor Lake, multiple generations after the last re-spin of Skylake.

Comment: Usually `static` only matters with `-fPIC`, where "global" functions can't inline because of symbol-interposition rules (for ELF targets anyway, IDK about Windows).   But `inline` should allow inlining anyway.  Making it `static` does give the optimizer heuristics more reason to inline it, since it doesn't also need to make a stand-alone copy of the function.  With only one call-site, the function size threshold for inlining is basically unlimited, IIRC.  Other than that, much faster benchmark times can be a methodology error, like letting the compiler optimize away some of the work.

Comment: I have thought of that too but when i just tried forcefully inlining or setting noinline made no difference and  -fopt-info showed no differences between the two variants (static vs no static), at least when it comes to optimization, not sure if that missed anything

Comment: Also still not about this actual problem, but while popcnt'ing the masks isn't bad, you can do better, see for example: [How to count character occurrences using SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54541129/555045)

Comment: @harold your suggestion to remove the statics for cmp1 cmp2 and the other m256i fixed the core issue :P

Comment: I'll have to check on Windows/MSVC if it fixes it there too, by the way the counter you provided I tried implementing it and it didn't yield a sufficient improvement (was in MoE) to justify the much reduced readability

Answer (score 1):

Changing these:

```cpp
    static __m256i cnk1, cnk2;
    static __m256i cmp1, cmp2;
```

to:

```cpp
    __m256i cnk1, cnk2;
    __m256i cmp1, cmp2
```

Fixed the issue, thanks Harold